# Why is my custom search folder criteria not being applied on some computers?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I've created an Outlook addin that uses AdvancedSearch to find all emails with a UserProperty defined by my addin.

This works on my own desktop and laptop, but doesn't work on my customer's device. We're both using the newest version of Outlook from Office 365, however he's on Windows 7 and I'm on Windows 10. I suspect this might be a Group Policy issue since he's part of an organisation, but telling him that isn't useful unless I can point at what specific policy needs to be changed, or what exactly is causing the issue, so he can tell the IT department exactly what's wrong.

I've enabled error messages so I can see any exceptions, but none show up. The only time an exception is thrown (to my knowledge) is when the addin attempts to create the folders if they're already there; if the folders are deleted, no exceptions are thrown by the addin.

This is the code that adds the search folders

```
private void SearchFolders(Outlook.Application application)
    {
        string scope = "Inbox";
        string filter = $"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/{userProperty} = true";
        Outlook.Search search = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folderInbox = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folderSentMail = null;
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;

        try
        {
            ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            folderInbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            //MessageBox.Show(folderInbox.FolderPath.ToString());
            folderSentMail = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
            scope = "\'" + folderInbox.FolderPath + "\'";
            search = application.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, true);
            search.Save("GDPR - indbakke");

            scope = "\'" + folderSentMail.FolderPath + "\'";
            search = application.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, true);
            search.Save("GDPR - Sendt post");


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace, "An exception was thrown");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (search != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(search);
            if (folderInbox != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderInbox);
            if (folderSentMail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderSentMail);
            if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
        }
    }
```

The variable userProperty is instantiated as a string at the top of the file, and is simply the name of the UserProperty.

The search folders are supposed to include any mails that have the UserProperty set to true. However, the inbox search folder will sometimes include all emails in the inbox, while the "sent mail" search folder will just include nothing at all.

I know that marking the emails works on his device, since the column I added to show this property shows up, and shows that the email is marked correctly. It's just the search folders that don't work.

Looking at the search criteria in OutlookSpy shows me that the criteria are different on my computer compared to his. My PC shows the following:

```
rt : RES_PROPERTY
res.resProperty :
  relop : RELOP_EQ
  ulPropTag : GDPRMarked (0x8532000B)
  lpProp :
    ulPropTag : GDPRMarked (0x8532000B)
    Value : true
```

while his PC shows this for the inbox:

```
rt : RES_EXIST
res.resExist :
  ulPropTag : PR_SUBJECT_W (0x0037001F)
```

and this for the outgoing:

```
rt : RES_PROPERTY
res.resProperty :
  relop : RELOP_EQ
  ulPropTag : http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/GDPRMarked (0x8569001F)
  lpProp :
    ulPropTag : http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/GDPRMarked (0x8569001F)
    Value : true
```

Comment: Is the search criteria wrong? Have you looked at the search folder through OutlookSpy (click IMAPIFolder button) and compared the search criteria (GetSearchCriteria tab) on both machines?

Comment: That might be possible. I'll have to have a look at that next time he's available

Comment: Turns out that the search criteria are different, even though it's the same version of the extension. I updated the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you never added the property to the folder fields (and hence specified the property type), Outlook will assume that "GDPRMarked" is a string property.

The right criteria shows `PT_BOOLEAN` property type (0x8532**000B**), the bad one specifies `PT_UNICODE` (0x8569**001F**).

Comment: I have no idea what this actually means from a practical perspective. The search folders were made by the extension on all computers, and they work on one pc but not another. Could you explain what I need to do to fix the issue, and where to do so? Or even just come with a suggestion as to the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: I can only speculate as to why - most likely GDPRMarked was already defined as a string property before, and the property type cannot be changed after it was used once in that mailbox . Note that your search criteria must use double quotes around the DASL property name

Comment: It does use double quotes. It was first tested on my machine as it is the development environment. I've tried deleting the folders and letting the extension create them again, but it's the same result.

Comment: If a particular mailbox is stuck with a string property type for a given guid/id, that mapping cannot be changed to a different type (e.g. boolean). You are stuck with the old type.